# Conversion of stored procedure from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to convert an old SQL Server stored procedure to Postgres function.

My function is not yielding the same result..

Is there any better way to do it?

I tried online tool https://www.sqlines.com/online It converts with lot of syntax error.

Then written a function using same logic..

**SQL Server**

```
USE [de**.****.designer]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AppDownloadForMonth]   
    @Subscription_Id int,
    @todayDate DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @eoMonth datetime;
    DECLARE @startoMonth DateTime;

    SET @startoMonth = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @todayDate), 0);
    SET @eoMonth = EOMONTH (@todayDate);

    WITH Last30Days AS
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, @startoMonth) DateValue
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateValue + 1
        FROM Last30Days   
        WHERE DateValue < @eoMonth
    )
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(date, Last30Days.DateValue) ASC) AS Row#,
        CONVERT(date, Last30Days.DateValue) AS DownloadDate,   
        COUNT(RA.DevicePlatform) AS DownloadsPerDay
    FROM 
        Last30Days 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM ReportingRegisteredApps 
         WHERE Subscription_Id = @Subscription_Id) AS RA ON (CONVERT(date, Last30Days.DateValue) = CONVERT(date, RA.RegistrationDate))
    GROUP BY 
        CONVERT(date, Last30Days.DateValue), RA.Subscription_Id
    ORDER BY 
        CONVERT(date, Last30Days.DateValue);
END
```

In PostgresSQL:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.usp_appdownloadformonth(p_subscription_id integer, 
   p_todaydate timestamp without time zone)
   RETURNS TABLE(rowno bigint, downloaddate character varying, downloadsperday bigint)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
   AS $function$
   declare err_context text;

   begin
   CREATE table Last30Days  (DateValue varchar(50));
   INSERT INTO Last30Days(DateValue)
   select CURRENT_DATE + i 
   from generate_series(1, cast(EXTRACT(day from (date_trunc('MONTH', now()) + INTERVAL '1 
   MONTH - 1 day')::date) as int) ) i;
   RETURN QUERY  SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY to_timestamp(Last30Days.DateValue, 'yy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS')  
   ASC) AS rowno,
   Last30Days.DateValue AS downloaddate,   
   COUNT(RA."DevicePlatform") AS downloadsperday
   FROM 
   Last30Days LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM "d**.***.*****".public."ReportingRegisteredApps" 
   WHERE "d**.***.*****".public."ReportingRegisteredApps"."Subscription_Id" = 
   p_Subscription_Id) AS RA
   ON (to_timestamp(Last30Days.DateValue, 'yy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS') =  RA."RegistrationDate")
   GROUP BY 
   Last30Days.DateValue, RA."Subscription_Id"
   ORDER BY 
   to_timestamp(Last30Days.DateValue, 'yy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS');
   DROP TABLE Last30Days;
   END;
   $function$
   ;
```

Comment: You don't need to create a table to store the "last 30 days" you can join directly to the result of `generate_series()` and obviously you can also use common table expressions (`WITH ...`) in Postgres as well

Answer (score 0):

The query can be translated more or less directly. A SQL function would be more appropriate for this

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.usp_appdownloadformonth(p_subscription_id integer, 
   p_todaydate timestamp without time zone)
   RETURNS TABLE(rowno bigint, downloaddate character varying, downloadsperday bigint)
as
$$
    WITH Last30Days AS
    (
        SELECT g.dt::date as DateValue
        FROM generate_series(date_trunc('month', p_todaydate),                  
                             date_trunc('month', p_todaydate) + interval '1 month - 1 day',
                             interval '1 day') as g(dt)
    )
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(date, Last30Days.DateValue) ASC) AS row_num,
        DateValue AS DownloadDate,   
        COUNT(RA.DevicePlatform) AS DownloadsPerDay
    FROM 
        Last30Days 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM ReportingRegisteredApps 
         WHERE Subscription_Id = p_subscription_id
        ) AS RA ON Last30Days.DateValue) = cast(RA.RegistrationDate as date)
    GROUP BY 
        Last30Days, RA.Subscription_Id
    ORDER BY 
        Last30Days.DateValue;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

`generate_series()` returns `timestamp` values and they are cast to a `date`  (i.e. without a time) inside the CTE. This removes the need for all the casting (convert) in the subsequent parts of the query.

`cast(RA.RegistrationDate as date)` is only required if `RegistrationDate` isn't defined as `date` (e.g. because it's a `timestamp)